# AuthorizeAttribute doesn't authorize user when credentials are given while the user is logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Asp.net mvc core (.NET Core 3.0), I have a controller action with `AuthorizeAttribute`

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,SuperAdmin")]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyProtectedView()
{
    //some stuff here
    return View();
}
```

If a user is logged in, and is added to a role, the Authorize will not allow them to get to `MyProtectedView` until they log out/in again. Tried refreshing, opening a new window, but nothing seemed to allow access until a log in action.

I know that I can get this functionality by calling `_userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Admin")`, (_userManager is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`), checking against the roles, and redirecting if the user is in none of them, but it would be nice if the attribute handled that

I'm wondering if there's a way to get the AuthorizeAttribute to work without the login action, or if I have to use a different mechanism for this to work?

**UPDATE:**, the permissions for User B are added by User A (currently, by running an insert script on the DB). I had assumed that in this case, the mechanism by which User A updates the permissions will not affect the claims cookie for User B.

Comment: It boils down to that user has to have their claims Identity/Principle reissued with the new role(s)/claims(s) before it takes effect for that logged in user.  Logout/Login does exactly this (reissues an updated claims ticket upon successful login).  If you can tie the role addition to a refresh of the claims Identity/Principle on the logged in user, then you could short circuit the Logout/Login.  However, it is not clear if the user is adding themselved into the role or if someone else is adding them.  The former would be much easier to circumvent logout/login than the latter.

Comment: Ok, I figured but wasn't able to find it in the docs -> if I understand you, AuthorizeAttribute is grabbing something from the identity cookie (this is what I'm not sure about) that is passed with the response, and isn't even going back to the DB (unlike IsInRoleAsync)?

Comment: Most probably this information is cached and you need to reset the cache (logout/login) before you get the new data. In the context of User Roles it seems quire reasonable. I don't think it's a good idea to go to the DB every time when you have a cookie/token with all the data you need. If however you need to get the change ASAP you can create your custom attribute and if the built-in authorization fails, make a call to the DB to check and if there are changes it's a good idea to add them to the roles, so you avoid another DB call for the same reason.

Comment: Correct - the roles are stored as claims in the ClaimPrinciple object in the authentication cookie.  Here is a site (https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-identity-claims/) that kind  of walks through basics of roles/claims and even in his examples, he states you have to logout/login to see the claims changes.  I'm having a hard time finding the exact way it works, but above should be the general gist.